# Creating line offset inwards from polygon by 1m and only on one side using QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer

I have street polygons and I need to create lines offset inwards by 1m, but only on one side and only along the sides of the streets, not intersections.

I tried using an inwards buffer and a one sided buffer, but this creates a buffer all the way around the inside of the polygons.
I have attached a picture, existing street segments in brown and the lines I want to create are in yellow. It doesn't matter which side of the road the lines are on.

[image]

Comment: You have a rather special use case. With polygons it is not possible because the boundary is one ring and you cannot offset just part of it. If you split and convert the polygons into line segments it will be hard to define which segments to offset and which not. It might work to create first the centerlines for the polygons and to offset the centerlines then but if the polygons are not all equally wide the result would not be correct - 1 m inwards from the boundary.

Comment: Depending what criteria you use to decide on which side of the road you want the buffer, you can automatize this or not. For this, we need more information. You might convert polygons to lines (as proposed by @user30184 then create (manually or automatically) an attribute for each line if it is one that should be buffered or not. In your screenshot, it seems that for each polygon, you want to buffer the side of the road that is farther north. Please specify / edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Managed to solve problem by finding centreline using voronoi skeleton, then using nnjoin to find distance between centreline and road edge, then using offset lines tool using distance by expression (nnjoin distance-1m) to give lines that are 1m from the road edge. There is also a function to choose left or right side within offset lines tool. This gave a generally good result.

Comment: Maybe adding as an answer?